# External StyleSheet (CSS) link to HTML5 file using TextEdit (MAC)

Tags: html, css, macos, stylesheet, external

I am taking my first web design class.  We are coding in HTML5 and CSS.  I have created an index.html document that works correctly when I use  and  to code the colors, fonts and layout.  Now the assignment is to remove the  section and replace it with a link to a CSS external stylesheet.  After doing this, my HTML file does not appear to be actually linking to my CSS file. Any help you can provide would be sincerely appreciated.

My HTML and CSS files are saved in the same file on my computer.  The file names are index.html and javajam.css .  I am using a MAC and TextEditor.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=“en”>
    <head>
        <title>JavaJam Coffee House Menu</title>
        <meta charset=“utf-8”>
        <link rel=“stylesheet” href=“javajam.css”>
    </head>
    <body id=“wrapper”>
        <h1>JavaJam Coffee House</h1>
        <br>
        <nav>
            <a href=file:///JavaJam/index.html>Home</a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href=file:///JavaJam/menu.html>Menu</a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href=http://music.html>Music</a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href=http://jobs.html>Jobs</a>
        </nav>
        <br>
        <dt>
            <strong>Just Java</strong>
        </dt>
        <dd>Regular house blend, decaffeinated coffee, or flavor of the day.</dd>
        <dd>Endless Cup $2.00</dd>
        <br>
        <dt>
            <strong>Cafe au Lait</strong>
        </dt>
        <dd>House blended coffee infused into a smooth, steamed milk.</dd>
        <dd>Single $2.00 &nbsp Double $3.00</dd>
        <br>
        <dt>
            <strong>Iced Cappuccino</strong>
        </dt>
        <dd>Sweetened espresso blended with icy-cold milk and served in a chilled glass.</dd>
        <dd>Single $4.75 &nbsp Double $5.75</dd>
        <br>
        <br>
        <footer>
            Copyright&copy 2013 JavaJam Coffee House
            <br>
            <a href=“mailto:kellie@mckinneyjackson.com”>kellie@mckinneyjackson.com</a>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```css
body {
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    color: #330000;
    font-family: Veranda, Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    background-color: #ccaa66;
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 200%;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav {
    text-align: center;
}
#footer {
    background-color: #ccaa66;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: small;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also a not an expert, but maybe your fault is the wrong quotation marks are not the right one.

“en” -> "en" ....

Here is the correctly version. I have tested it and it works.
I have add  type="text/css" media="screen", but I will be without it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>JavaJam Coffee House Menu</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="javajam.css">
</head>
<body id="wrapper">
    <h1>JavaJam Coffee House</h1>
    <br>
    <nav>
        <a href=file:///JavaJam/index.html>Home</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href=file:///JavaJam/menu.html>Menu</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href=http://music.html>Music</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href=http://jobs.html>Jobs</a>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <dt>
        <strong>Just Java</strong>
    </dt>
    <dd>Regular house blend, decaffeinated coffee, or flavor of the day.</dd>
    <dd>Endless Cup $2.00</dd>
    <br>
    <dt>
        <strong>Cafe au Lait</strong>
    </dt>
    <dd>House blended coffee infused into a smooth, steamed milk.</dd>
    <dd>Single $2.00 &nbsp Double $3.00</dd>
    <br>
    <dt>
        <strong>Iced Cappuccino</strong>
    </dt>
    <dd>Sweetened espresso blended with icy-cold milk and served in a chilled glass.</dd>
    <dd>Single $4.75 &nbsp Double $5.75</dd>
    <br>
    <br>
    <footer>
        Copyright&copy 2013 JavaJam Coffee House
        <br>
        <a href="mailto:kellie@mckinneyjackson.com">kellie@mckinneyjackson.com</a>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I have tried adding the additional information in the <link> but it still does not work.  I cannot figure out what you mean about the quotation marks.  I think mine look different because of the font, but if you could clarify this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is my quotation marks!  I copied and pasted your quotation marks but I don't know where to get them in the future.  The quotation marks that show my document are from the " key on my keyboard.  Any ideas on where to get the correct quotation marks?

Answer (score 0):

You want to:

1. System preferences > Keyboard > Text > Uncheck "use smart quotes and dashes"
2. TextEdit > Preferences > Uncheck "smart quotes" and "smart dashes"
3. TextEdit > Edit > Substitutitons > Uncheck "smart quotes' and "smart dashes"

This is a Mavericks problem.

Comment: Thank you!  I have made the changes.  You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you will NEVER EVER have FTP or HTTP anywhere in the file paths,UNLESS you're referring to an external link. MAKE SURE you have everything inside of a folder that's the name of the project, in this case let's say it's monkey, THEN, inside that folder, put your CSS in a folder called CSS, and inside of that title the CSS main.css or styles.css, and your photos are in a folder called MEDIA, and let's say in your MEDIA folder we have 2 files, a photo there named beaver.jpg, and a photo named DOG.JPG. NEXT, take your INDEX.HTML, MENU.HTML, JOBS.HTML, and MUSIC.HTML. and put it in the folder called monkey, this is the main folder of the project, consider it the ROOT folder. You DO NOT EVER use c:/jonsmith/desktop/monkey ANYTHING. IF you have a C:, or ANY ?: drive letters in the file path, THEN your html WILL NEVER work correctly. From there, your NAV files will ONLY be:

"href="monkey/index.html"> Home "

"href="monkey/music.html"> Music "

"href=monkey/jobs.html> Jobs "

"href="monkey/menu.html"> Menu "

MINUS THE " "

NO MORE HTTP OR FTP in the FILE PATHS, THEY ARE INCORRECT!

Secondly, emphasis WILL ALWAYS BE < em> words go here < /em>

forget the space after the beginning <, I had to do it for it to show up, otherwise you would just see  *DOG*

ALL TAGS WILL BE   DOESN'T MATTER IF IT'S P TAGS, H TAGS, OR WHATEVER, THEY ARE ALWAYS:

"< P> THIS A SENTENCE TAG "

"< H1> THIS IS THE H1 "

"< EM> THIS IS THE EMPHSIS TAG "

"< HEAD> THIS IS THE HEAD TAG "

MINUS THE " " and the space after the beginning < in each line. I had to do it this way to make it show up correctly otherwise you would just see

## This is the H1 tag

.

THEY WILL ALWAYS BE PAIRED.

ANY TIME YOU HAVE AN = SIGN, SUCH AS " < a href="monkey/index.html">Home "  OR EVEN " < IMG SRC="SOMETHING.JPG"> " THEN YOU ALWAYS USE THE "WORDSHERE" METHOD.

again, deleting the space of the beginning < on each line.

Third, let's say you have an image, < IMG SRC="MONKEY/MEDIA/beaver.jpg" ALT="a photo of a beaver"> ALWAYS USE AN ALT TAB FOR PEOPLE WITH DISABILITIES, NUMBER 1., NUMBER 2, THE " " RULES WILL APPLY TO RULE 1, 3.LET'S SAY YOU HAVE AN IMAGE, < IMG SRC="monkey/media/beaver.jpg">, and you wanted to add dog.jpg as well. Then the commands for that would be:

" < img src="monkey/media/beaver.jpg"> "

then you will add

" < img src="monkey/media/dog.jpg"> "

MINUS THE " " and the beginning space after the beginning < on each line.

SINCE they are in the same folder and in the same directory, then the ../ is not needed. LET'S SAY YOU WANTED AN AUDIO TRACK, AND IT'S IN A FOLDER CALLED monkey/AUDIO, AND YOU HAVE A FILE CALLED ROCKON.MP3, THEN YOU SHOULD USE THE ../ COMMAND. ../MONKEY/AUDIO/ROCKON.MP3. HOWEVER, IF IT'S IN THE MEDIA FOLDER, THEY YOU WOULD USE THE PATH MONKEY/MEDIA/ROCKON.MP3.

Lastly, USE a program called "brackets" to do your HTML in because it will help you auto close your <> tags and other commands, and when your in DOUBT, always refer to w3.org, it's a website that you can go to for assistance with html and css. I suggest you look over it and see how things are suppose to look like. AND FOR THE LOVE OF GOD, LOSE THE FTP AND HTTP because your file paths are INCORRECT, this is 80% of the issue. HTTP refers it being a browser item, meaning the link is somewhere that's EXTERNAL, AS IN SOMEWHERE ON THE INTERNET when it's not, and FTP is a file transfer protocol, meaning you're trying to link to a file on a file server. IF YOUR FILES ARE LOCAL, SUCH AS A computer, FTP AND HTTP do you no good. the FTP AND HTTP are referring to the outside WORLD, if it's local, such as your laptop computer, THE FTP AND HTTP are NOT needed. NOW, let's say you're referencing to something on google.com, then yes, you SHOULD use the HTTP rule which would be https://www.google.com/search?q=mouse&biw=1280&bih=884&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUlO6T7_jKAhWF5yYKHXQYBAYQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=RCa64rFGKx9lnM%3A, otherwise DON'T DO IT, ALWAYS use monkey/media/beaver.jpg, or whatever path you use.

ONE MORE BIT OF ADVICE, < link rel=“stylesheet” href=“javajam.css”> WILL WORK, BUT SOME BROWSERS WON'T SUPPORT THAT METHOD, INSTEAD USE < link rel=“stylesheet” type="text/css" href=“javajam.css”> it's just safer.

again deleting the space at the beginning <

HOPE THIS HELPS.

Comment: You should take a look at the "How to Format" section when you type posts.